# Multiple Where conditions in same query and row

Tags: sql

I have a table with data like the below (there are more ITEMID each with a values for MODULESTYPE 0,1 and 2

```
ITEMID  MODULETYPE  UNITID
E-MA0860S   0   base
E-MA0860S   1   purch
E-MA0860S   2   sales
```

what I would like to do is get this into one row

```
ITEMID  Base UOM    PUOM    SUOM
E-MA0860S   base    purch   sales
```

Comment: What's the expected result if an ITEMID  has only one or two entries?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The answer may depend on the dbms.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some think like this

```
SELECT ItemID, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN MODULETYPE=0 THEN UNITID END) AS [Base UOM]
       MIN(CASE WHEN MODULETYPE=1 THEN UNITID END) AS [PUOM]   
       MIN(CASE WHEN MODULETYPE=2 THEN UNITID END) AS [SUOM]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ItemID
```

Comment: that is superb, just what I was after - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use self join

```
  select  a.ITEMID,  a.UNITID as UOM, b.UNITID AS  PUOM , c.UNITID as SUOM
  from my_table a
  inner join my_table b on a.ITEMID =  b.ITEMID and b.MODULETYPE=1
  inner join my_table c on a.ITEMID =  c.ITEMID and c.MODULETYPE=2
  where a.MODULETYPE = 0
```